# Access secured procedure without showing login form in Worklight v6.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, realm, worklight-adapters

I have valid username, password for access secured(security test with realm) procedure. 
I need to access secured procedure without asking or showing login form.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: When you say that you have the username/password … you mean that the username/password is already available in JavaScript?  If that is the case, then your challenge handler can go straight to submitting them w/o displaying a login form.  If the username/password are not available in JavaScript … then I'm not sure what you are asking.  You might add more details on your scenario.

Comment: Yes, I will have username and password in javascript. If I don't have values for username and password, I would not be able to access secured procedure.

Answer (score 1):

you can manually set authenticated user identity in adapter code with WL.Server.setActiveUser API. Once user identity is set - secured procedure invocation will succeed. 
Basically - create unprotected proc1 and protected proc2. invoke proc1, set user identity, invoke proc2 from proc1.

Comment: I have two adapter like SQL, HTTP Adapters. I have set the User identity in SQL Adapter's procedure as sqlProcedure().

  "WL.Server.setActiveUser ("myRealm", {
   userId: "My Name",
   displayName: "First Name",
   attributes: {
    "mailID" : "myname@domain.com"
   }
  });
  httpProcedure("myname@domain.com");"
  
And I'm trying to invoke (Http secured procedure) httpProcedure() from sqlProcedure(). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Form based authentication. Change your `authenticationConfig.xml` file and change the authentication and login modules to something else (some other way in which you can receive username and password). [Basic authentication using HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) is a good way for which you can use a [Header authenticator](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/devref/r_header_authenticator.html?resultof=%22authentication%22%20%22authent%22%20)

Comment: can you share any sample project for Headerbased authentication?

Comment: I don't know of a sample. However, it is pretty straightforward. All you have to do is add a header to your request. See the documentation of header login module for more information http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_header_authenticator.html&resultof%3D%2522authentication%2522%2520%2522authent%2522%2520